# If $f=g$ almost everywhere, then $\int_E f = \int_E g$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions, almost-everywhere

One task in the book Analysis 2 by Tao is to prove the following Proposition 8.2.6:

Let $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ a measure space and $f,g \colon E \to [0,\infty]$ $\mathcal{E}$-measurable functions on $E$.

If $f=g$ almost everywhere, then $\int_E f = \int_E g$.

My problem is not to prove the claim. For example let $A = \{f \neq g\} \in \mathcal{E}$, then $f = \chi_A f + \chi_{A^c}f$, $g = \chi_A g + \chi_{A^c}g$ and $\chi_{A^c}f = \chi_{A^c}g$. So we have $\int_E f = \int_A f + \int_{A^c} f$, when we know that interchanging sum and integral is possible. Then it's easy to show the rest. ($\chi$ is indicator function)

But the only properties I have available are:

- $\int_E f = \sup \left\{ \int_E g : g \text{ is simple, } 0 \leq g \leq f \right\}$
- $f_E f = 0 \Leftrightarrow f=0$ almost everywhere
- $\int_E cf = c \int_E f$, $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $c \geq 0$
- $f \leq g \Rightarrow \int_E f \leq \int_E g$

Comment: what you do after : "my problem is not to prove the claim..." is rather unclear, and quite wrong.

Comment: Why? I use $\int_A f = \int_E f \chi_A$ for $A \in \mathcal{E}$. $\int_{A^c} f = \int_{A^c} g$ and $\int_A f =\int_A g = 0$ are clear because $\mu A = 0$.

Comment: (As you showed below.)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your formula. I thought you wrote $f=f\chi_A+f\chi_{A^c}=g\chi_A+g\chi_{A^c}$. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

Your statement is equivalent to prove that if $N$ is a null set, then $\int_Nf=0$.

- First, see what happen with simple function.
- Then, if $f\geq 0$, from one of your property, there is a sequence of simple function $(g_n)$ s.t. $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_N g_n=\int_N f.$$
- Finally, set $f^+(x)=0\vee f(x)$ and $f^-(x)=-(f(x)\wedge 0)$, where $a\wedge b$ denote the minimum of $a$ and $b$ and $a\vee b$ denote the maximum. Remark that $f^\pm \geq 0$. Then, if $f$ is unspecified, write it as $f=f^+-f^-$, and apply the previous step.

Comment: Using $\int_E \sup_n f_n = \sup_n \int_E f_n$ for $0 \leq f_1 \leq f_2 \leq \dots$ is the same as using that interchange of sum and integral is possible. My question is whether you can solve the problem without these properties.

Comment: I didn't used such property. I used $\int_E f=\sup\{\int_Eg\mid 0\leq g\leq f\text{ simple}\}$. @Heraklit

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail why my statement is equivalent to showing that the integral over zero sets vanishes? Without using $\int (f+g) = \int f + \int g$

Comment: Instead of considering $h=f-g$ we can suppose WLOG that $g=0$. Then, what you have to prove is that if $f=0$ a.e., then $\int f=0$. What you know (by one of your the property you mentionned) is that on $A=\{f=0\}$, $\int_A f=0$. Then, what you have to prove is that $\int_{A^c}f=0$. Since $A^c$ is a null set, then it's enough to prove that $\int_N f=0$ for all null set $N$. @Heraklit